# Get subgraphs by group and calculate network modularity in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, igraph, network-analysis

I have a network dataset of ~80 schools (nodes are the students in each school). I need to calculate modularity for each school. Ideally, creating a new data frame with only school ID and the school's modularity score.

The data is restricted so I can't post it, but here is a toy example:

HAVE DATA

```
student_id    school_id    friendid_1    friendid_2    friendid_3    friendid_4
1             101          3             NA            NA            NA
2             101          5             2             3             NA
3             101          2             4             5             NA
4             101          1             6             NA            3
5             101          1             NA            6             2
6             101          5             NA            2             1
7             201          8             NA            NA            NA
8             201          NA            9             NA            NA
9             201          8             7             NA            NA
10            201          7             9             NA            NA
11            301          19            15            NA            12
12            301          20            NA            19            11
13            301          15            19            11            NA
14            301          16            NA            12            18
15            301          17            20            17            NA
16            301          14            19            20            13
17            301          20            18            13            14
18            301          13            NA            19            17
19            301          17            NA            16            11
20            301          13            17            11            14
```

WANT DATA (just the school id and modularity scores

```
school_id    modularity
101
201
301
```

Below is what I've tried. I first created a dataframe of just the school IDs. Then tried a for loop where I grabbed all the respondents by school and made a graph of them to calculate modularity, then putting it into the school DF. This didn't work:

```
schools <- as.data.frame(unique(df$school_id))


for (school in 1:length(unique(df$school_id))){

  g <- graph_from_data_frame(school, directed = FALSE)

  sg <- igraph::simplify(g, remove.loops = TRUE)

  cl <- cluster_fast_greedy(sg)

  schools <- modularity(cl)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
df$school_id <- as.factor(df$school_id)

school_list <- list()

for (i in levels(df$school_id)){
     schl <- subset(df, school == i)

     schl_g <- graph_from_data_frame(schl, directed = FALSE) %>%
               igraph::simplify(., remove.loops = TRUE)

     schl_clust <- cluster_fast_greedy(schl_g)

     schl_mod <- modularity(schl_clust)

     id_mod <- select(df, school) %>%
               subset(., school == i) %>%
               unique() 

     id_mod$schl_mod <- schl_mod

     school_list <- c(list(id_mod), school_list)
}


schools <- bind_rows(school_list)
```